# PySide6 failing to run

Tags: python, pyside6

I've recently installed PySide 6.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04
Attempting to run my code on VSCode
And have just ran: export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1

I'm getting the following message:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/home/omari/anaconda3/envs/gui_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled PySide 6 and am still unable to get it to run. I'm not sure what I'm missing in that message as to what I need to do.

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
import sys
import random
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "Hei maailma", "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World",
                                     alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which is only the "Create a simple application" copy and pasted directly from the website.

Any ideas on a fix? Or more information needed?

I have yet to come across any solutions from qt.io's forums, or any other articles pertaining to this issue.

**EDIT**

So far I've come across one work around. I can open the file directly from the terminal. It still isn't working when trying to run through VSCode though.

**EDIT2**

There's a chance this can be a VSCode Extension issue. PySide, or QT for that matter, saves files in .ui. My code here is in .py. When changing it to .ui VSCode was prompting me for the proper extension to open it with. I haven't opened it yet, but I believe that to be how I should be looking at this. For it to open in the terminal, but not VSCode, tells me that it's something VSCode doesn't have.

Comment: Have you tried installing PySide6 without anaconda? Anaconda tends to have these problems with Qt.

Comment: I haven't. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hey man, I'm getting the same message. Within Anaconda, and now not, I've created a virtual environment when installing PySide6.

Answer (score 1):

So!!!!! I've FINALLY gotten it to work.

In my workspace window, all I had to do was right click the file, and run current file in interactive window. VSCode prompted that I download a Jupyter notebook kernel, and then it worked!

Alternately, run your code with Ctrl + Alt + N, as opposed to Ctrl + F5. Make sure you have the Code Runner extension installed.

Considering the file worked in my terminal, I knew it had to be something I was or wasn't doing in VSCode. So yeah, case closed.

I had put it down for a while to focus on these courses I've started taking, so it wasn't that I was stressing myself out with this the whole time. My solution came about as I was trying to get matplotlib to show a graph that I was trying to get to run (first time using matplotlib), and that's what worked for that. So it dawned on me to try it for this code, then boom, it indeed worked the same way.

So yeah, don't stress yourself out when something isn't working the way you want it to.